# Logic App in ISE - Event Trigger (Storage) doesn't trigger whereas LogicApp outside ISE triggers for the same event

Tags: azure-logic-apps, eventtrigger

I am trying to test Event Trigger in Logic App (Storage Events).

Logic App in pay per use subscription gets triggered based on Event.

The same logic app inside an ISE Environment doesn't get trigger.

Is there any special setting for ISE which should be activated ?

Thanks
Prabath

Answer (score 0):

The **Event Hub connector is not support ISE version** now.

For logic apps that you create and run an isolated integration service environment (ISE), the Logic App Designer identifies built-in triggers and actions that run in your ISE by using the CORE label. Managed connectors that run in an ISE display the ISE label, while connectors that run in the global, multi-tenant Logic Apps service don't display either label. This list shows the connectors that currently have ISE versions.

[image]